# ImportRow from DataTable to another and still destination DataTable is Empty VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

Hi I'm trying to copy one row from DataTable to another, I looked almost everywhere and I can't find a reason why this is happening, I'm using ImportRow and still the New DataTable is empty.

Here's one of the answers similar I found and It's still not working!:

```
   Dim newTable As New DataTable
        Dim dsFrom As New DataTable

        For Each DBShoes In list
            Dim iShoeID As Integer
            iShoeID = DBShoes.sShoes_ID
            dsFrom = DBShoes.GetFullShoeDetails(iShoeID)
            For Each dr As DataRow In dsFrom.Rows
                newTable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray)
            Next
        Next
        GridView1.DataSource = newTable
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

Error: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

Here's the Import that doesn't crash but nothing is added in the DataTable:
    Dim newTable As New DataTable
            Dim dsFrom As New DataTable

```
        For Each DBShoes In list
            Dim iShoeID As Integer
            iShoeID = DBShoes.sShoes_ID
            dsFrom = DBShoes.GetFullShoeDetails(iShoeID)
            For Each dr As DataRow In dsFrom.Rows
                newTable.ImportRow(dr)
            Next
        Next
        GridView1.DataSource = newTable
        GridView1.DataBind()

    Else
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a form with two DataGridView controls on it.
Here is the code of form:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' create table with single column
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    dt1.Columns.Add("Number", GetType(Integer))

    ' create another table with single column
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    dt2.Columns.Add("Number", GetType(Integer))

    ' fill first table with single row
    Dim r As DataRow = dt1.NewRow()
    r.Item(0) = 1
    dt1.Rows.Add(r)

    ' import all rows of first table into second table
    For Each row In dt1.Rows
        dt2.ImportRow(row)
    Next

    ' show tables
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt1
    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt2
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, all I had missing   newTable.Columns.Add("sShoes_ID", GetType(Integer))